# Manual supersampling instead of default AWT antialiasing?

Tags: java, awt, antialiasing

In our application we use java.awt.Graphics2D and java.awt.image.BufferedImage for drawing/rendering. To enable antialiasing we set (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON). Although in a multithreaded environment (when we have multiple simultaneous requests to render something) the performance seems to degrade. We suspect that underneath the AWT is using some static synchronised method when performing anti-aliased rendering. Is our presumption correct?

What would be the best remedy for that? Would supersampling work in this case i.e. rendering a larger image first in a big resolution and then downscaling it to the desired one?

Comment: All painting eventually ends up been synchronised through a single rendering pipe line, so that the hardware can deal with it in a sequential manner, so, if you're pushing content to the screen, then yes. One solution might be to paint your content to a BufferedImage first. Another solution might be to render your content 4 times larger then you need it   (I think) and scale it down to the size you need (with the correct sampling method)

Comment: I am not pushing the content to the screen. It is rendered on the server and then some clients can display it.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide an example of what you are doing...